# magento setpage show first page even if the page doesn't exist

Tags: collection

i have a category

```
TV category ()
  TV (2) <br>
  16" ~ 22" (3) <br>
  24" ~ 29" (7) <br>
  32" ~ 39" (8) <br>
  40" ~ 50" (1) <br>
  3D (0) <br>
  4K Ready (2)<br>
```

In phtml

```
<?php foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) : ?>

       <?php $products = $this->getProducts($subcategory); ?>

       ....show product info

<?php endforeach ?>
```

In block class

```
public function getProducts(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $subcategory)
{
    if (!isset($this->_products[$subcategory->getId()])) {
        $products = $subcategory->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addUrlRewrite($subcategory->getId())
            ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC')
            ->setPage(3, 3);

    }
    return $products;
}
```

The problem is that when i use setPage (3, 3), the product will still print the first page of the TV subcategory which only contains two product. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
->addUrlRewrite($subcategory->getId())
```

This loads the collection, everything after this doesn't do anything about the sql query.

Therefore you have to change the order:

```
$products = $subcategory->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC')
        ->setPage(3, 3)
        ->addUrlRewrite($subcategory->getId());
```